# WP redirects pretty permalink to query string

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type `artist` and a taxonomy `kind_of_art`.
I want their permalinks to be like:

`%kind_of_art%/%artist%`

Therefore I created following rewrite rules:

```
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?kind_of_art=$matches[1]&post_type=artist&artist=$matches[2]',
    'top'
    );
```

If I go to `photography/sam-sample` for example, I am redirected to `?artist=sam-sample`.
If I add a front base to my rewrite rule it works.

### Additional info

An `artist` post consists of multiple textareas with different content. I use this technique to create virtual subpages (e.g. `press`, `gallery`, `biography`). Of course I need rewrite rules again:

```
  add_rewrite_tag('%artist_sub_page%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_rule(
    '([^/]+)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)',
    'index.php?artist=$matches[2]&artist_sub_page=$matches[3]&kind_of_art=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
```

Funnily enough, *this* works even without that front base.

Any ideas whats wrong? I assume this is an easy issue, but I am no expert in rewrite rules.

### EDIT:

I just discovered two things:

If I visit my `/photography/sam-sample/` I will be redirected to `?artist=sam-sample`. But if I enter my wanted URL again, I am not redirected and it "works". I guess this is why I already thought a few times that I got it working but a minute later it wasn't ;-)

If I visit append any string to my wanted URL structure – e.g. `photography/sam-sample/foo` or `photography/sam-sample/foo/bar` – I am also not redirected.

### EDIT #2:

I got it working now with this regex:

```
([^/]+)/([^/]*)
```

By working I mean I can visit `/photography/sam-sample` and it will work. One problem to solve still:

In my navigation I create the links dynamically with `get_permalink()`. This function still outputs `?artist=sam-sample` instead my wanted structure.

Comment: are you not planning on using the `page` post type? your rewrite rule will break requests for `page/subpage`, that's why custom post types use a unique slug.

Comment: I also use pages (which are accessible at the moment) and posts (but their permalinks is not important as I do not want to display single posts). I don't want the custom post type to be on top level but my custom taxonomy.

Comment: your rule captures `/page/subpage/`, so I don't see how that could possibly work, unless you're only using pages a single level deep. but same situation with a taxonomy *or* cpt, they both typically have unique slugs.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I do not need more than top level for pages. And: At the moment I have 4 different kind_of_art-slugs. As I didn't get an archive page to work I created pages with a page template that queries the posts of the kind_of_art.