# Query var SEO URL

Tags: query-variable

I've created a personal custom variable in a plugin. Now I've URL of this form: `http://example.com/page/?var=ID`. I want to have this kind of URL: mysite.com/page/var/name where name is retrived from the database based on ID.

This is how I created the var:

```
function personal_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "var";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'personal_var' );
```

This is how I link var:

```
.add_query_arg( "var", ID, "/page/" ).
```

Comment: If your URI really is `var?=ID`, then there's something wrong. Query string arguments/parameters are of the style `key=value`. The question mark `?` separates those arguments from the actual query (separated by `/`). If you need to append _additional_ key/value pairs, then you chain them with an ampersand `&`: `https://example.com/foo/bar?baz=bingo&dragons=alot` for e.g.

Comment: I made a mistake, sorry, my URL is ?var=ID

Comment: Still a typo or is it really a trailing slash followed by a question mark `/?`?

Comment: It's really `mysite.com/page/?var=ID`. Please note that link is inserted in /page/

Comment: Then you probably have a bogus `.htaccess` or other Apache/nginx rule that adds a trailing slash no matter what. Or you don't abort somewhere in some script and in fact return an empty string or add a trailing slash in PHP if there is something to appended or not. Maybe just a missing check to abort if something is `empty()` or `! isset()`.

Comment: Default page URL in wordpress is mysite.com/page/ so if I add a variable it should normal that the URL is page/?var=ID, isn't it? In mysite.com/page/ I load a php function via a shortcode of my personal plugin.
Looking at here, it seems that my url are fine: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: @testermaster Yes, it's OK to call the way you are calling. Also, asked and answered at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/129399/wp-redirects-pretty-permalink-to-query-string